# Any benefit if advertise /24 between my ASs that connect through eBGP using private ASs?

Tags: bgp

Let's say I'm migrating my network to new infrastructure. So, the new site and the old site are connected using private ASs. I wonder if there is any benefit for the new site to advertise /24 along with >=/25 to the old site. The old site only advertises >=/25 to the new site.

Comment: What address blocks do each site use?  Do they both use a  /25?

Comment: @Ron Trunk No, the shortest prefix in my network is /28, most use /29. They are scattered around.

Comment: What's the shortest prefix that you can summarize all your subnetworks at each site?

Comment: If it's a /25 that's all you need to advertise